# How to read html form contents using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a html form in which I can add input element dynamically using jquery.
At the end I want to submit/read all data on the form. I used serialize method but it gives me data of elements that were originally on form and not if dynamically added elements.

Here is my work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function call(class_name) {

            console.log(class_name);
            $("#new_append_pass").append('<input type="password" class="username_' + class_name + '" name="pass">');
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count = 0;
            var alt, str;
            $(".user_pass a ").click(function () {
                $("#append_me").append('<input type="password" class="' + $("#append_me").attr("alt") + '" name="pass">');
            });

            $(".new_user_pass a ").click(function () {
                count = count + 1;
                alt = $("#new_append_me").attr("alt") + "_" + count;
                str = '<input type="text" class="username_' + count + '" name="username">' +
                '<input type="password" class="' + alt + '" name="pass">' +
                '<span alt="username_' + count + '" id="new_append_pass"></span>' +
                '<a href="#" onClick="call(' + count + ')" class="add_new_pass"> Add another pass </a>';
                $("#new_append_me").append(str);

            });


            $("#submit").click(function () {

                var get_class_name = $(".user_pass").find("input[type=text]").attr("name");
                var get_class_name1 = $("#new_append_me").find("input[type=text]").attr("name");
                console.log($("." + get_class_name).serialize());
                console.log($("." + get_class_name1).serialize());
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="user_pass">
            <input type="text" class="username" name="username" />
            <input type="password" class="username" id="username" name="pass" />
            <span alt="username" id="append_me"></span>
            <a href="#">Add another pass </a>

            <div class="new_user_pass">
                <a href="#">Add another user </a>
                <span alt="username" id="new_append_me"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

How to read contents of dynamically added form elements???

Comment: your whole structure is messed up. The `<div>` elements  for new_pass and new_user are nested. So trying to get `<input>` for each is complicated. And your `<a>` links are messed up. Click on Add another user, Add Another pass also gets fired.

Comment: where is your form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider following steps to improve your markup structure. It is tough to decode your snippets in Fiddle.

1. Each `<input>` element has a different class, different attributes. And you are trying to access them using common selector.
2. Your `<a>` links should have a unique attribute or a selector. Both get fired on Click of 'Add Another User'
3. Try to use separate `<div>`s or atleast appropriate selectors for accessing two different sets of `<input>` elements.
4. NONE of the `<input>` elements has a same class. So `$('classname').serialize()` will never work for your elements.
5. `.attr('name')` for getting class? Wrong logic; as the 'name' attributes for each `<input>` are NOT same.
6. Use delegation using .**[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**, in case of dynamically generated elements.
7. Keep a common convention; either class selector or Id's, don't mix them.

And here is your **Fiddle Solution**. Made changes in Html attributes, click events and almost everything.

Comment: Thnks Shaunakde.. But when I add new password textbox to dynamically added div it gets added to first div only.

Answer (score 1):

Locate them by their class/id using the ever lovable `$(query)`, and depending on the input type, locate their value through that query. Some use `$(query).value`, some use `$(query).text`, checkboxes uses `$(query).checked`. Look them up the jQuery API or just `console.log($(query))` and look it up on the console. (ctrl+shift+J on chrome).

By the way, if you're going to add classes to one-time stuff (as in you're never going to use the same class again), you're better off using IDs.